# How to hide label from Sencha Touch Ext.TabPanel?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I would like to have solely icons on the Ext.TabPanel.

If I set the title to an empty string, there is still a  element below each icon. How to make Sencha Touch hide the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce the problem. Here is my code :

```
new Ext.TabPanel({
    fullscreen:true,
    tabBar: { 
        dock: 'bottom',
        layout: { pack: 'center' } 
    }, 
    items:[{
        title:'',
        id: 'card1', 
        iconCls: 'rss', 
        layout: 'card' 
     },{
        title:'',
        id: 'card2', 
        iconCls: 'rss', 
        layout: 'card'
    }], 
});
```

And this is what I get :

[image]

So could you add a printscreen of the tabs or a print screen of the firebug view to see what element you are talking about.

Comment: I want to have only the icon rendered. The title (or label) should be hidden.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad. Anyway what do you mean "There is still an element below each icon" because I just tried what you did and I can't see any element under the icons.

Comment: There is an "<span style="" id="ext-element-59" class="x-button-label">&nbsp;</span>" element.